# Java FX ComboBox drop down list

Tags: javafx, drop-down-menu, combobox, javafx-8

Can anyone tell me why some items from a dropdown list are not visible when running the jar application? It seems to happen randomly. I create an ObservableList, then recursively create a Line, assign it a stroke type from the observable list through a String as line.setStyle("-fx-stroke-dash-array:" + dashString + ";"). Finally, everything works fine and the ComboBox gets the whole list of line and a certain selection. But it sometimes fail to display lines in the dropdown list. The code is:

```
package test;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboLines extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ComboBox<Line> dashCombo = new ComboBox<>(); 
        initDashLineCombo(dashCombo, dashUnit, 2);
        dashCombo.getStylesheets().add("test/style.css");                                                                                                      
        dashCombo.setStyle("-fx-min-width: 100; -fx-max-width: 100; -fx-pref-width: 100; -fx-min-height: 15; -fx-pref-height: 15; -fx-max-height: 15;");  
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(dashCombo);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 150, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void initDashLineCombo(ComboBox<Line> cb, ObservableList<int[]> list, int i)
    {        
        ArrayList<Line> LinesList = new ArrayList<>(); // to store lines        
        // cycle over the list and generate a line with dashing defined by list
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int[] dash = list.get(j);
            String dashString = " ";
            for(int k : dash) // cycle over an int array which defines the dashing
                {   dashString += k + " ";
                    sum += k; }
            System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
            Line line = new Line(15, 0, 1*(15+sum), 0);
            System.out.print("\ndashString :" + dashString);
            // apply style
            line.setStrokeWidth(2);// line width
            line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            line.setStyle("-fx-stroke-dash-array:" + dashString + ";"); // line dashing
            LinesList.add(line); // collect the line          
        }
        // create the observable list
        final ObservableList<Line> LinesObs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(LinesList); 
        // set all line items in the combo box
        cb.setItems(LinesObs);         
        // select an item ion the combo box
        cb.setValue(LinesObs.get(i-1)); 
    }
        // ... dashing ...
        int[] s10 = {1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3,}; 
        int[] s9 = {1,3,1,3,1,4,5,4,5,4, 1,3,1,3,1,4,5,4,5,4};
        int[] s8 = {6,3,6,3,6,5,1,5, 6,3,6,3,6,5,1,5}; 
        int[] s7 = {1,3,1,3,1,6,6,6, 1,3,1,3,1,6,6,6};
        int[] s6 = {5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3}; 
        int[] s5 = {5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4}; 
        int[] s4 = {5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4}; 
        int[] s3 = {5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 1, 3}; 
        int[] s2 = {15, 3, 15, 3, 15, 3}; 
        int[] s1 = {60}; 
        final ObservableList<int[]> dashUnit = FXCollections.observableArrayList(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10);

}

     /* style.css */

     .combo-box {
      -fx-min-width: 35;
      -fx-pref-width: 35;
      -fx-max-width: 35;
      -fx-min-height: 20;
      -fx-pref-height: 20; 
      -fx-max-height: 20; 
      -fx-padding: -2 -8 -2 -5;
       }
     .combo-box-base > .arrow-button { 
     -fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0, 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0; 
     -fx-background-color: transparent; 
     -fx-alignment: center-left; 
       }
     .combo-box .cell {
     -fx-font-size: 8.75pt; 
     -fx-font-family: "Arial";
     -fx-text-fill: BLACK;
     -fx-alignment: BASELINE_RIGHT;
     -fx-padding: 0 3 0 -5;
      }
```

[invisible lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayZeh.jpg)

UPDATE: Using cell factory a simplified version (no CSS and no dashing applied) is like this. The same problem persists and further I cannot get the initial selection applied.

```
 package test;    
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
 import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
 import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
 import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
 import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.util.Callback;

 public class ComboLines extends Application 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }   
     ComboBox<Line> dashCombo = new ComboBox<>();     
     @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
     {    
         StackPane root = new StackPane();
         root.getChildren().add(dashCombo);
         dashCombo.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(DASHUNIT));
         dashCombo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
         dashCombo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Line>, ListCell<Line>>()
    {
    @Override
        public ListCell<Line> call(ListView<Line> newLine)
        {
            return new ListCell<Line>()
            {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Line item, boolean y) 
                    {
                        super.updateItem(item, false);
                        setGraphic(item); 

                    } // end updateItem
            } ; // end new ListCell
        } // end call()
    }); // end setCellFactory

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 150, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
    }

    Line line1 = new Line(15, 0, 50, 0), line2 = new Line(15, 0, 50, 0), line3 = new Line(15, 0, 50, 0); 
    final ObservableList<Line> DASHUNIT = FXCollections.observableArrayList(line1, line2, line3);
}
```

Finally, I got it working with the code below. Following kleopatra's comments, the insipartion came from the official Oracle page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html

```
ComboBox<Line> dashCombo = new ComboBox<>(); 
dashCombo.getStylesheets().add("style.css");                                                                                                      
dashCombo.setStyle("-fx-min-width: 100; -fx-max-width: 100; -fx-pref-width: 100; "
        + "-fx-min-height: 15; -fx-pref-height: 15; -fx-max-height: 15;"); 
initDashLineCombo(dashCombo, common.General.DASHUNIT, (numberCoils - i), colCombo); 


public static void initDashLineCombo(ComboBox<Line> cb, ObservableList<int[]> list, int i, ColorPicker cp)
{        

    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) // cycle over the list and generate a line with dashing defined by list
    {     
    int[] dash = list.get(j);   
    String dashString = " ";
        for(int k : dash) 
        dashString += k + " "; 
        Line line = new Line(25, 0, 95, 0);
        line.setStrokeWidth(2); line.strokeProperty().bind(cp.valueProperty());
        line.setStyle("-fx-stroke-dash-array:" + dashString + ";");    
    cb.getItems().add(line);    
    }     
    cb.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(i-1);

        cb.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Line>, ListCell<Line>>() 
        {
        @Override public ListCell<Line> call(ListView<Line> p) 
        {
            return new ListCell<Line>() {
                private final Line line;
                    { 
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY); 
                        line = new Line(0, 0, 70, 0);
                        line.setStrokeWidth(2);
                        line.strokeProperty().bind(cp.valueProperty());
                    } // end Line
                @Override protected void updateItem(Line item, boolean empty) 
                    {   
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item == null || empty) {   
                                setGraphic(null);
                            }
                        else {
                            line.setStyle(item.getStyle());
                            setGraphic(line); 
                            setItem(line);
                        }
                    }  // end updateItem()
                  }; // end ListCell
            } // end call()
        }); // end setCellFactory
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrskJ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMgwv.jpg)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's unclear how you create the lines/where `dashString` comes from ect.

Comment: Hi Fabian and thank you for your availability! I updated the post with a complete working example. I am open to alternative implementations which would not fail to display the lines correctly.

Comment: don't add Nodes to the combo (they would have to be added to both the button and the list which is impossible). Instead add the dashes as data and implement a cellFactory that uses a Line and set the style from the item. BTW, unrelated to the problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Thanks kleopatra! I just tried to implement it using a setCellFactory. It works, I can see the dash lines in the combo but the same problem persists. They dissapear from the list as soon as they are clicked. It must be something else I think.

Comment: please update the example with your latest changes

Comment: Done now. Please see my update. Thank you!

Comment: you still add nodes (lines) as data to the combo - don't! Repeating: instead add the dash data (styles) as data and configure the line (in the cell) with that style.

Comment: Can you please indicate a suitable example on the web. This method to use Cell Factory is new for me and with what I found browsing I could only produce the code you see above. Thank you!